# Cant show sub-checkbox

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a checkbox list, if a check one of the checkbox, all of the check box will appear. I already hide the sub-checkbox by php but when I'm trying to check one of the checkboxes that allows to appear all the sub-check box it doesn't work.

Here's what I got so far (I used php also to show & connect the list of main checkbox that is stored on the database and as you can see I used prepared statement [bind]):

```
<form action="avfunc.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal well">
<div id="updatediv">
    <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Update Reference" style="width:100px; display:none;" class="edit" />
</div>
<fieldset>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <?php
            $tsql = "select * from medtest";
            $tstmt = $con->prepare($tsql);
            $tstmt->execute();
            $tstmt->bind_result($mti,$mtn);
            $tstmt->store_result();

            while ($tstmt->fetch()){
                    $d1= '<input type="checkbox" name="test"
                     value="'.$mti.'" onClick="var e=document.getElementById("updatediv"); var s=document.getElementById("update"); e.removeChild(s) ; this.form.submit();">'.$mtn.'<br> ';
                    echo $d1;

            }       

            ?>      
        <?php if($_POST['checkbox'] == "3"){ ?>
        <h4>Laboratory Examination</h4>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="1"><span>Complete Blood Count</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="2"><span>Blood Typing</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="3"><span>Urinalysis</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="4"><span>RPR/TPHA</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="5"><span>Hepatitis B screening</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="6"><span>Fasting Blood Sugar</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="7"><span>Creatinine</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="8"><span>Total Cholesterol(Low Cholesterol, High Cholesterol)</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="9"><span>Triglyceride</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="10"><span>VLDL</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="11"><span>Blood Uric Acid</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="12"><span>Anti-HAV Igm Screening</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="13"><span>Anti HBaAg</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="14"><span>Drug & Alcohol Test</span></div>
                    <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="15"><span>Stool Culture</span></div>
                    </div
                    <?php } ?> >
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that PHP will not send the "hidden" HTML out when your main checkbox is set - so there is no content to be conditionally shown.

You'd be better off using CSS style `display: hidden` to hide the checkboxes you don't want as the HTML will still go to the browser (it just won't be displayed). Then, when the user checks the checkbox, you can use javascript to change the CSS style to `display: initial` for those elements to display again.